# Should search engines be allowed to index wp-includes and wp-content in WordPress?

Tags: seo, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, noindex

Should the `wp-includes` and `wp-content` directories in WordPress be indexed by search engines or not? Should we prevent indexing using `noindex` in X-Robots tag?

Answer (score 1):

*This answer relates to Google*

---

Google seeks to index webpages, images, and PDFs that contain *content*. Files such as scripts and stylesheets are used to render pages and etc but they're generally not going to index that stuff because it isn't content.

Assuming your goal is strictly about preventing indexation, you shouldn't really have to do anything. However, at some point I *would* recommend you ensure that your permissions set properly within `/var/www/html/` or `/var/www/your-site/`.

That being said, here are some ways you might `noindex` things:

**Using a `<meta>` Tag**

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

**Using an HTTP Response Header**

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
...
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

### Path of Least Resistance?

I'm imagining realistic scenarios where there's things within either of the directories you specified where I'd want `noindex` explicitly provided. This Nginx location block (may) ensure that images within `/uploads/` that have a filename prefixed with "noindex-" have `noindex` headers when search engines request them.

```
location /uploads/ *~ (noindex-.*\.(png|jpg|webp|jpeg))$ {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ (Googlebot|Googlebot-Image|Bingbot|DuckDuckBot|Slurp|Baiduspider|YandexBot)) {
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex";
  }
}
```

^ Wrote that off the top of my head. Not tested. Someone will correct if I made a mistake.

### WordPress File and Folder Permissions

There are plenty of exceptions to these rules, it depends on the the complexities of a given site and its hosting provider. These are general best practices.

- All Directories should be `750` or `755`
- All Files should be `640` or `644` except for `/wp-config.php` which is often set to `600` (depending on its group). This file should be either `640` or `600`

If you're not familiar with reading permissions here is how you can get the octal permissions from your command line:

`stat -c "%a %n" /var/www/html/wp-includes/`

You can implement any changes that might need to be made with commands like these:

```
find html/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
find html/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

Replacing `html/` with your proper document root.

Comment: Mike, your suggestions are based on assumptions about the document root location which might not be accurate for the OP.  e.g. a typical cPanel site would be at /home/(user)/public_html or /home/(user)/www (assuming a default symlink). To then give them a CLI command based on your assumption could have unforeseen consequences.

Comment: @Steve I said "with commands _like_ these:"

Comment: Yes, but these answers will (hopefully) be around for a long time and become a reference point.  If they are taken literally by someone without a lot of knowledge...

Comment: I added context

Comment: Mike, I think you mean that normally wp-includes and wp-content (except wp-content/uploads) would not get indexed as they don't contain webpages, images and content. So there is no need to do anything for them. For wp-content/uploads, we can add no-index header to the images files. Is that correct?

Comment: I use cPanel with Apache. Since I had not included Options -Indexes in .htaccess, some webpages containing directory listings got created within subdirectories of wp-includes. These pages then got indexed by google. They were appearing in search results which I did not want. So I had to use 1.URL removal tool to remove them from google index, 2.add Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" line to .htaccess for wp-includes (also for wp-content) to prevent them from being indexed again and 3.Add Options -Indexes in .htaccess in public_html to prevent such pages from being created again.